# Break long url in text editor to 80 characters, keeping it functional and respecting indentation

Tags: html

I code mainly in Python, so proper indention is an important issue. I have some html code that contains a very long url. Something like this:

```
<div id="main_content_wrap" class="outer">
  <section id="main_content" class="inner">       
    <p align="justify">
    Aaa bbb ccc, ddd <a href="http://www.example.com/asaslkdsdfkjsd/fkjsdlfsdlfjsdlf/kjsdlfkj/sldfjslkdfj/skldfjklsdjf">Long link</a> eee.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

If I break that url indenting it to align with the above line (`Aaa bbb...`), it won't work anymore in the live html since spaces are inserted. The url will thus point to:

http://www.example.com/asaslkdsdfkjsd/%20%20%20%20fkjsdlfsdlfjsdlf/kjsdlfkj/sldfjslkdfj/skldfjklsdjf

(notice the inserted string `%20%20%20%20`). I am forced to break it so that the second line begins at column 1, ie:

```
<div id="main_content_wrap" class="outer">
  <section id="main_content" class="inner">       
    <p align="justify">
    Aaa bbb ccc, ddd <a href="http://www.example.com/asaslkdsdfkjsd/
fkjsdlfsdlfjsdlf/kjsdlfkj/sldfjslkdfj/skldfjklsdjf">Long link</a> eee.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

This keeps the url functional, but I don't like it because it does not respect the indentation of the code.

This seems like a rather simple issue, but I haven't found a proper solution.

Comment: Just ignore PEP-8 here.

Comment: It's not just PEP8 (also, this is html code, not Python). I use Sublime Text to code, and not respecting indentation means that I lose the ability to fold blocks of code

Comment: I meant that you should ignore the line length limit and just not break the line.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood you. I prefer to break code at the standard 80 chars limit. It makes it more readable.

Comment: @Gabriel In this case, it's a trade-off between one unreadable thing and another. Pick the one that's less unreadable -- in this case, the one that doesn't break Sublime.